# Using an SQL queried array for an html image source in Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, homestead

I'm doing a laravel project. I save user's profile pictures in a folder on my server, and the path to that photo in the db table. I use a sql query to form an array with all the information, and then am able to access the information in HTML like this: `{{profile.FirstName}}` etc. I am trying to display the user's profile picture.

I have tried doing `<img src="profile_pictures/{{profile.username}}"` and also `src={{profile.profilePic}}` where the profilePic cell has the path to the photo, and neither work. Should I try saving the path in the table with quotes around it and then try the second option? Or is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: What are the values that are output in the html? Are you indeed getting the correct path to the image? I'm assuming you're wanting something like `<img src="profile_pictures/johndoe.jpg" />'.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. If i was to put `<p> {{profile.profilePic}} </p>` it would output `profile_pictures/johndoe.png`

Answer (score 1):

use `asset()`

> **asset()** Generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS). [See More](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset)

Consider User Model have `profile_picture` attribute

Where `$user->profile_picture` wil give you image path stored in path

For example:

```
echo $thatUser->profile_picture;
//Will show this path "profilepictures/thatUser/image.jpg
//Real path: project/public/profilepictures/thatUser/image.jpg
```

To show that image in view use `asset()`

```
<img src={{ asset($thatUser->profile_picture) }}" alt="that user image"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you right click and view page source is it showing the correct path? If you're using Angular partials stored in the public folder of the Laravel project, make sure that path from the partials directory to profile_pictures directory is correct. If your using views in the resources folder same thing goes.